# Does my integrated video suppport 1920x1080?

Tags: windows, resolution

I just got a new monitor (Dell S2209W) which requires 1920x1080 resolution.  I'm running vista (business) and using an Intel integrated video.  When I go into my display settings there is no option for 1920x1080.   When I look at the Standard VGA Adapter properties and look at the "List All Modes" it doesn't show 1920x1080.  Do I need to buy a new video card?

-Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked up the monitor.

It really depends "how old" the Intel integrated video is. I ran a 1280x1024 display without problems on a Intel Extreme Graphics 2 display with no problem (and that was about 4 years old).

If yours is newer, I do not see why it could not run 1920x1080, just do not expect to play a high resolution game with good frame rates... (although at the time, I did manage to play Half Life 2 quite well!)

Also, If I was you, go in to your BIOS and assign more memory to your graphics. If you want descent performance, you may want to turn it up to the maximum (ram depending).

If you are seeing just "standard VGA Adapter" you may want to go to the [Dell website](http://www.dell.com) or [Intel website](http://www.intel.com) to actually install the correct drivers as this can make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks.  Intel had a utility to update my drivers and now I can do what I wanted.

Comment: The BIOS is not the place to change the amount of video memory. In shared memory architectures nowadays the video memory portion of the RAM is done by the driver and dynamic.

Comment: The BIOS is still the place for the majority of motherboards. It is mainly only the high end ones with the good integrated graphics that have drivers for this feature. I support many businesses and recently got a bunch of brand new quad core machines on a 6 month old motherboard, and I still had to do this in the BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

> Standard VGA Adapter

you better install the drivers for your video adaper, 'Standard VGA Adapter' is the generic windows VGA driver.

and if you ask such a question, the model # of your Intel GMA would be a very valuable piece of information. :).

Comment: Ah .. that makes sense.  If I could mark both answers as "the answer" I would :)